How do I use a registry within a supervision tree with child_spec name: {:via} syntax for other supervisor children?
I am learning elixir & I am struggling a bit with how to set up separate processes for data access & API routing while allowing them to communicate in a way that allows either process to fail while still being able to reconnect / be connected to via the new child process upon the next request. It seems that the Registry module is the answer for where to store this information, but I am struggling to get it to work the way I expect just from reading the hexdocs & am finding the {:via, ...} syntax is not setting my registry key.
Currently, I have a supervisor which has 3 child processes - a Registry, a GenServer (storage) & a Plug.Router module. I initialize the registry first, then the storage using name: {:via, ...} to try & store the storage module's PID in the registry. Last I want to access that storage key in the registry in the router, but I haven't gotten that far yet as I am struggling to get the registry key to register.
I was able to get the router to have the GenServer PID by passing it explicitly as an argument on application start & making the router store it as an Agent so I know my router / GenServer code works when I do that, but this approach is very weak & means if the GenServer fails, the router has an out of date PID (defeating the whole purpose of having the supervisor for restarting processes).
My start code in the application module:
def start(_, _) do 
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Usersystem.Supervisor]

    {:ok, supervisor} = Supervisor.start_link([], opts)

    {:ok, _} = Supervisor.start_child(supervisor, {Registry, keys: :unique, name: Usersystem.Registry})

    {:ok, _storage} = Supervisor.start_child(supervisor, {Usersystem.Storage, name: {:via, Registry, {Usersystem.Registry, "storage"}}})

    {:ok, _router} = Supervisor.start_child(supervisor, {Plug.Cowboy, scheme: :http, plug: Usersystem.Router, options: [port: 8080] })

    res = Registry.lookup(Usersystem.Registry, "storage")
    Logger.info(res) # I get an empty result instead of [{pid(), value}], which tells me the storage key is not being assigned to. 

    {:ok, supervisor}
end

Can anyone give me some advice about what I am missing in this start function that is preventing this key from being initialized using the {:via, ...} syntax, or if I am misunderstanding any part of how registry's work with this code? Also open to the idea that I'm barking up the wrong tree, as I am quite new to Elixir. From what I understand I could use named processes as well, but I would think using Registry gives me a bit more control about what I do w/ my processes down the line so I would like to learn how it works.
I am using Elixir 17.3 & Erlang/OTP 27.

You are after DynamixSupervisor which is designed to work with a registry and {:via, _, _} names. Supervisor is the static beast.
